# Unexpected behavior when DELETEing from TABLE in SQL

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, razor

I have done it before, but it's not working this time.

All I'm trying to do is delete an entry from a table, and as you can see, it is supposed to output "ok" if it succeeds, (and I *have* manually checked the querystring data and everything matches what its trying to delete, even all the conditions are also met), but it isn't deleting.

```
@{
    var message = "";
    try
    {
        var d = Database.Open("tgyytuyt");
        var query = "DELETE FROM Cart WHERE OrderId = '" + Request.QueryString["Value"] + "' AND UserId = '" + Request.QueryString["SubValue"] + "' AND PartNumber = '" + Request.QueryString["Final"] + "'";
        d.Execute(query);

        message = "ok";
        //Response.Redirect("~/OSM/Default.cshtml");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        message = ex.Message;
    }
}
<p>@message</p>
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong that could be causing the item to not be deleted?

Comment: what's `Database`? are you getting any exceptions? what exactly happens when this code runs?

Comment: Just as an aside, it's worth noting that writing code like this makes your website open to SQL injection attacks in the worst way possible.  I'm sorry if you might not find this pertinent to your question - but seeing `Request.Querystring[]` whilst constructing a SQL statement is asking for your website to be annihilated.

Comment: @Codo - this is not MVC. This is WebPages.

Comment: @BENDR, have you tried putting a breakpoint on `d.Execute(query)`, and pasting that string directly in to Management Studio Express, or mySQL Query Browser and running it there?  Does it delete the rows, or give you some kind of another message?  Whenever I have had issues with SQL statements not doing what I expected, my first port of call is to run it myself against the database and analyse what happens.

Comment: presumably if its not getting to `message = "ok"` then it must be throwing an error that is getting caught... What is outputted in message?

Comment: What gets outputted now is "ok". But it's not ok, because it still isn't working. Thanks all for your advice and suggestions/answers, but I'm still having issues. I'd post more code or _something_ but, there's really nothing else to post :S

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is, that there is no row in your database which meets the conditions of your where clause.

Check that first.

But without more information about the value of your querystring and your database setup its all guessing.

It might also be a trigger...

Comment: Thanks @Jan. It's still not working. The exact code works fine in other sites i've played around with, but just not this one. Like I stated in my question, everything in the db matches querystring data

Comment: So have you tried to execute the generated query in Management Studio? Do you have triggers on the table?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your execute is doing, but you should be executing a non-query. You might want to check on that.

Comment: I am executing a non-query, i just got into the habbit of naing my "sql statement" variables "query" etc etc. Also, don't be fooled by variable names.